# Select a random Item but bias by voting score?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, random

I have a list of items which have upvotes (likes) and downvotes (dislikes).
Now, I would like to randomly select an item from this list, but bias towards items with a more positive score.

```
chance = random + (upvotes - downvotes)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: One way is to get a random number in a large range (larger than that of the known items), then assign values for the 'higher scores' that are wider.  E.G.  1 is -7 score, whereas 13-20 are for +7 score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to retry low scored items.

```
while(true) {
    Item item = items.get(random.nextInt(items.size()));
    if (chanceOfSelecting(item) > random.nextFloat())
        return item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

1. Assign a weight to each item.
2. Add all the weights together, and create a random number from 0..total weight.
3. Start looping through the items, subtracting the weight of each from the random number as you go. When you reach 0 (or lower), stop, and you have your randomly selected item.

Comment: I'd just like to add that the weight should probably be something like `1 + upvotes - downvotes` or just `1` if `downvotes >= upvotes`. Or maybe `upvotes` could have higher value.

Comment: Downside: O(n) to find a single item.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, this is of course not very efficient for large collections. There are however many ways to optimize this if necessary, but to do that efficiently we need more information about the data.